# Rails ActiveAdmin how to use model scope inside admin after_create block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've got model `Book` which has a db column called `status` and defined scope like below:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  STATUSES = %w[planned acquired].freeze

  validates :status, inclusion: { in: STATUSES }

  scope :acquired, -> { where(status: 'acquired') }
end
```

Now inside of ActiveAdmin `admin/books.rb` I want to use that scope to check if book was acquired, like below:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Book do
  (...)

  after_create do |book|
    BookInfo.create!(book: book)
    BookCost.create!(book: book) if book.acquired
  end
end
```

Is it possible to use model scope inside of code not for scoping views or filters? with current code I'm getting:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `acquired' for #Book:0x00007fa22ce65458):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `acquired` is a scope, you would have to write:

```
if book.in?(Book.acquired)
```

Or

```
if book.status == 'acquired'
```

Comment: Which basically means that ActiveAdmin doesn't support AR scopes

Comment: I don't understand your comment. AA does 'support' them via its ```scope``` dsl statement. Maybe you expected even more magic? You could make a convenience method in your model ```def acquired```. Scopes in AR are defined on the ```class``` level, not the instance level.

Comment: I expected the same behaviour as in a regular Rails class which means if I have an AR object I can call scope on it. If this is 'more magic' then yes, I expected more 'magic'.